# scale intensity of MP4 to counts originally collected by the camera

Tags: image-processing, camera, mp4, video-processing, imaging

I have data that I saved as mp4 files and contain intensity for a fluorescent signal, however because they were exported in mp4 format the intensity shown in the image is less than in the original data.

Is there any simple way to maybe multiply a factor to the mp4 data to obtain an approximation of the original counts? Thanks!!

Comment: ever heard of gamma mapping? it's not that simple.

Comment: @M.Ochoa Are you able to recover the original counts through an image editor? For example: If you save a frame as image and then use that image in an editor, is there any options (levels? gamma? exposure? etc) that gets you close?